# Is it possible to price a trade on Bloomberg open API

Tags: c#, api, finance, bloomberg, trading

I have a requirement to compare my companies pricing of trades with an unbiased market source, eg Bloomberg or Reuters. So I want to be able to take a basic trade, eg an FX spot, forward, vanilla option etc and run it through our local pricing engine which will use our locally sourced FX rates as the rate to price on. I then want to be able to send the same basic trade structure to somewhere like Bloomberg to obtain their quoted price based on their rates and then compare their pricing to ours. But so far on BBG API I can only see how to retrieve rate ticks and market data, not how to price an instrument.

Is this possible? Has anyone done something similar or can suggest any other APIs that I might be able to use?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, AFAIK you should be able to send an order to Bloomberg Tradebook via API. I found [this link](http://www.bloombergtradebook.com/content/uploads/sites/2/2012/08/release_2009-11-23.pdf) where they announce this API. I know this is possible when trading equities, it might also be possible when trading FX. You should contact a Bloomberg representative to get a quote.